# Having SlowDown Error when calling PutObject operation to S3 bucket, does it help if I partition the folder from now without changing current files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, partitioning

I have a big folder that stores too many files and now I'm experiencing error:

```
An error occurred (SlowDown) when calling the PutObject operation (reached max retries: 4): Please reduce your request rate..
```

I don't want to touch the existing files, like moving them over to another folder or creating more sub-folders and putting them in. On the other, I will still need to put new files in that folder but will put them accordingly in different folders, like `../year=2022/month=10/day=3/file.json`.

Will it help? From my perspective, the error only happens because my current partition contains too many stuff which makes the query too time-wasting; having sub-folders underneath will have the query operations on another partition.

Comment: In S3 that bucket you should be using prefixes in order to parallelize reads. You are not really putting the files in another folder you just add a clever key that acts like a partition boundry and that will greatly reduce the seek time for S3 files.

Comment: And remember if the bucket location you are pushing too is far away you can always look into S3 Transfer Acceleration...

Comment: @RossBush thanks for your conclusion! So in your opinion, I'm making the addresses longer (by creating sub folders), is it equivalent to make another key? I hope this helps reduce query time.